# Proof from Axioms

Tags: logic, proof

Given the axioms

- Henry owns a bike
- Every bike owner loves racing
- No one who loves racing buys a scooter.
- Either Henry or Bob bought a scooter, which is named Bill

Did Bob buy the scooter?

This is a homework question; it seems almost too easy, so I just want to check to make sure my logic is correct.

Since either Henry or Bob bought a scooter, and since Henry owns a bike and therefore loves racing and therefore cannot buy a scooter, then Bob must have been the one to buy the scooter.

Am I correct in my logic and my answer?

Comment: Voted to close as off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about logic instead of directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legend:

```
Owns a bike === A
Loves racing === B
Buys a skooter === C
```

Rephrase the logic conditions:

```
Henry is A
A => B
B => Not(C)
Henry or Bob is C
```

Calculations:

```
Henry is A => Henry is B => Henry is Not(C) => Bob is C
Meaning: Bob bought a skooter
```

So yes - you are correct.
If it seems easy, it may be just to understand the tools you should use, to get you ready for more complex problems.

Comment: Sorry, the contrast on my screen didn't let me see the check mark, so I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation yet. :)